# Angular2 rxJS HTTP Observable Interval - Do something while waiting

Tags: angular, rxjs

**I have the following component that is subscribing to a service:**

```
this.nodeSummarySubscription = this.netStatusService.getNodeSummary(10000).
    subscribe(
        data => {
            this.offlineNodes = data.NodesFullyDown;
            this.filteredOfflineNodes = data.NodesFullyDown;
            this.nodesOnCellularBackup = data.NodesOn3G;
            this.offlineNodesSubject.next(this.offlineNodes);
            this.cellularNodesSubject.next(this.nodesOnCellularBackup);
            this.incidentNodesSubject.next(data.MonitoredNodes);
            this.isApiCallComplete = true;
            this.myDate = new Date();
            console.log("Refreshed at " + new Date());
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("Call complete")
    );
```

**On my service which executes the HTTP call during every specified interval:**

```
getNodeSummary(interval: number) {
        return Observable.interval(interval).flatMap(() => {
            return this.http.get(this.baseApiUrl + '/HomeApi/NodeSummary/').map(res => res.json());
        });
    }
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is it that on page load, my page takes the defined interval to make the   call?  Is there a way to fire the HTTPcall right away the first time, and only fire it every x interval after?
2. I want to be able to display some sort of a message on the page every time a data refresh (HTTP call after expired interval).  Is there another event on the Observable that I can attach to so that I can understand when the timer expired event is triggered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You want to use the `.timer()` operator instead of the `interval`. First argument is first delay, second argument is the interval in which the Observable is triggered.

```
getNodeSummary(interval: number) {
    return Observable.timer(0, interval).flatMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(this.baseApiUrl + '/HomeApi/NodeSummary/').map(res => res.json());
    });
}
```

2) You should create another `Subject<boolean>` e.g. `loading$` which you will `.next(true)` when you start loading, and `next(false)` when the call returns.

```
private loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();

loadData() {
  this.loading$.next(true);
  this.nodeSummarySubscription = this.netStatusService.getNodeSummary(10000).
      subscribe(
          data => {
            this.offlineNodes = data.NodesFullyDown;
            this.filteredOfflineNodes = data.NodesFullyDown;
            this.nodesOnCellularBackup = data.NodesOn3G;
            this.offlineNodesSubject.next(this.offlineNodes);
            this.cellularNodesSubject.next(this.nodesOnCellularBackup);
            this.incidentNodesSubject.next(data.MonitoredNodes);
            this.isApiCallComplete = true;
            this.myDate = new Date();
            console.log("Refreshed at " + new Date());

            this.loading$.next(false);
        },
        error => console.log(error),
        () => console.log("Call complete")
    );
}
```

Now you can add an alert in your template like

```
<div class="alert alert-default" *ngIf="loading$ | async">
   Loading
</div>
```

and it will be displayed if you call `loadData()`

Comment: Can you please provide an example?  I am very new to this. and reading a response like this isn't very clear to me.